# Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64: getRNGstate() and putRNGstate()

Tags: c, r

I'm writing a gibbs function in C and want to use random number functions such as rnorm().

My code is like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <R.h>
#include <Rmath.h>
void foo(int *nin, double *x)
{
    int n = nin[0];

    int i;
    GetRNGstate();

    for (i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        x[i] = rchisq(2);
        Rprintf("%f\n",x[i]);
    }
    // exit R random-gen routine
    PutRNGstate();
}
```

However when I tried to BUILD in Xcode, the error messages are:

```
> Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:   "_GetRNGstate",
> referenced from:
>       _gibbs in main.o   "_PutRNGstate", referenced from:
>       _gibbs in main.o   "_Rf_rchisq", referenced from:
>       _gibbs in main.o   "_Rf_rnorm", referenced from:
>       _gibbs in main.o   "_Rf_runif", referenced from:
>       _gibbs in main.o ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64 clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see
> invocation)
```

I'm using Xcode and I know that I have both R and R64bit. On Terminal $R runs R64bit and my Aquamacs also runs R64bit. I don't know whether it is a collide over different versions and if so, how can I convince Xcode to refer to R correctly?

Btw I found that the R.h and rmath.h files are in at least 3 places! I don't know which path should I relocate in Xcode! **Currently I'm adding the header path same as the 3rd one. And all #include works fine.**

```
R.Frameworks/Headers
R.Frameworks/Versions/2.15/Resources/include
R.Frameworks/Versions/Current/Resources/include
```

etc

But either way, a C function without getting any rnorm()-like functions will work and R can use it through dyn.load().

So please HELP!

Much Appreciated!

Comment: Well, I used Terminal to compile, say, R CMD SHLIB main.c then use dyn.load() blar blar... It works! wtf... Why Xcode cannot figure out those getRNGstate()??

Comment: Pay closer attention to the complete gcc lines when you invoke R CMD SHLIB -- as R knows what to link with, it works. I fear your call to Xcode is simply incomplete.

Comment: Thanks Dirk, when I deal with Xcode, I only click on the Build button, so I actually don't know which compiler Xcode is calling.. Can I say in R CMD SHLIB main.c actually R is the compiler?

Answer (score 1):

Your question is incomplete and not reproducible for lack of actual code.  There are a few issues I can suggest:

1. There are symbols with leading underscores in R. All the symbols you fail to link are routinely used as `PutRNGstate()`, `Rf_rchisq()`, ...  Maybe you just need to fix a switch you accidentally set?
2. It is not clear from your post whether you want something to be load into R as a dynamic extension, or whether you want to write a standalone program using these R functions. You can do both.
3. Calling a self-written function can be trivial.  By leaning on Rcpp, we can even do
   `cppFunction('double foo(int df) { return Rf_rchisq(df); }')` and call `foo(3)`
   repeatedly (because Rcpp deals with the RNG state for us via its `RNGScope` class).
4. If you want something standalone, look at the Writing R Extensions manual and the Rmathlib library.  I have posted small examples before.

Comment: Thanks very much for your response. I just edited my post to show the original code. My motivation for doing so it that in R I have to write some for loops and cannot use apply(), so I want to move that part into C to speed up. But inside the loop I already used bunches of R functions (say, RNGs, apply() etc) so I have to make sure RNG works. Actually later on maybe I'll see if apply() works in C. Otherwise I may have to convert all apply() into for loops again...

Comment: I'm not familiar with cppFunction(). Does that mean in c/cpp you can get rid of RNGstate() functions but simply write rchisq()? Then call it in a cppFunction in R it works?

Comment: In short, yes. And `rchisq()` is even vectorised so you can get `N` draws in one call. But do read the Rcpp documentation -- and see examples, eg at http://gallery.rcpp.org

Answer (score 0):

Analysing only the compiler output, it is failing to find the piece of code that implements those functions. Usually they are implemented in libraries and, maybe, your are failing to pass to it the set of libraries that your code must link to.

What I want to say is that you must compile, or verify that your scripts are compiling your code with something like that (assuming that you are using a gcc compiler):

gcc -o program main.o -llibrary1 -llibrary2 ...

where those libraries come from your framework (Just to remember, if your library is called libxxx.so you must pass to gcc -lxxx )

Comment: Thanks for your response! I think library path went fine. Cuz I added the R/.../include into the path and at least Rprintf() works. It's just the getRNGstate() putRNGstata() keep failing.. and I have no idea why. Btw if I use R CMD SHLIB in Terminal it works again.. Is this a Xcode problem?